# Scrollable Screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the below code, but I am facing this issue in some devices. What is the correct way to use scrollview? I am new to the flutter world so I am getting bit confused. I also tried `SingleChildScrollView` but it was of no help to me or maybe I don't know the right way to use it.

```
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  body: LoadingIndicatorPage(
    loading: _loading,
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.brown,
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new ExactAssetImage("graphics/register_bg.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: LEFTRIGHT_PADDING, right: LEFTRIGHT_PADDING),
          child: AnimatedOpacity(
            opacity: _currentOpacity,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                        child: Text(
                          AppLocalizations.of(context).registerTitle,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            AppLocalizations.of(context).registerNameHint,
                            style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFieldInput(
                        inputType: TextInputType.text,
                        textEditingController: nameController,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                .registerPhoneNumberHint,
                            style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFieldInput(
                        inputType: TextInputType.text,
                        textEditingController: phoneNumberController,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            AppLocalizations.of(context).registerEmailHint,
                            style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFieldInput(
                        inputType: TextInputType.text,
                        textEditingController: emailController,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                .registerPasswordHint,
                            style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFieldInput(
                        inputType: TextInputType.text,
                        textEditingController: passwordController,
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                .registerRepeatPasswordHint,
                            style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFieldInput(
                        inputType: TextInputType.text,
                        textEditingController: repeatPasswordController,
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                        child: CheckboxListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            AppLocalizations.of(context).registerTerms,
                            style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                          ),
                          value: true,
                          onChanged: (bool value){},
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: Button(
                      text: AppLocalizations.of(context).registerRegister,
                      buttonOnPressed: _createAccount),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).registerLogin,
                        style: TextStyle(color: textGreen)),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is the registration screen code.

[image: img]

Comment: Please include a sample code in your question.

Comment: Without code, it's difficult to know how best to solve this issue.
At a guess, I'd say you want to wrap your scaffold body with a `SingleChildScrollableWidget`. If you want the register button to stay at the bottom of the screen, then change from a column with your fields to a list view.

Comment: Please share your source code.

Comment: @Mobina Source code added..

Comment: @AlexMeuer SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: Let me know if my solution solved this for you. Please accept my answer if it did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have two nested `Columns`, remove one of them since it's not necessary.
2. Wrap the `Column` with a `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.brown,
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new ExactAssetImage("graphics/register_bg.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: LEFTRIGHT_PADDING, right: LEFTRIGHT_PADDING),
            child: AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _currentOpacity,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use List view instead of cloumn ,it does away the need of wrapping column inside single child scroll view

Comment: This solution can work but set primary=false so tht the page wont show the scroll bubbles if it turns out to be scrollable (if the content of the page can decrease to the point tht the page isn’t scrollable)

Answer (score -1):

For reference, this is Flutter’s recommended solution. And what worked for me.

**TL;DR:** Replace `Expanded` Widgets with `Flexible` and set `fit: FlexFit.loose` and set the Columns `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`.

```
Comlumn(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxiseSize.min,
  Children: [
    Flexible(
      fit: FlexFit.loose,
      child: Container(...),
    )
  ]
)
```

This is the error OP is receiving (based on the comments below). The error message describes why this is happening.

My answer is from the last paragraph.

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
>
> When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height
> constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try
> to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on
> a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to
> fill the remaining space in the vertical direction. These two
> directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its
> child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
>
> Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using
> FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather
> than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
> themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would
> otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to
> shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
> constraints provided by the parent.

Comment: No, still the same

Comment: Can you add the full error code to your question. Or at least the relevant part if it’s really long

Comment: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: Ah. I believe you should also set the columns’ mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min.   Let me know if that worked

Comment: Good! Just for reference if you read through the error you’re getting, it gives my answer as the solution.